# How to POST whole html table data using Django?

Tags: html, django, django-views

Created a html table with three columns and 26 rows which is mapped to the Django views.py file.

Was trying to post all html table data into DB using Django views.py file.

Please find my `views.py`:

```
def create(request):
    form = Scrum.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST" or "None":
        
        form.save()

        
        context = {
            'form': DBData
        }

        return render(request, "scrum.html", context)
```

`scrum.html`

```html
<form method="POST" action=".">

    {% csrf_token %}

<table class="example-table multiselectable is-centered" id="table" contenteditable="true">
<tbody><tr><td class="selected">1</td><td class="selected">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td class="selected">1</td><td class="selected">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
</tbody></table>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" placeholder="Submit">

</form>
```

After clicking "Submit" button, all my provided data in table should be saved in DB.

My model will be shown as below:

`models.py`

```
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    TaskName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    AssignedTo = models.TextField(max_length=70)
```